# AngualrJS Conditional or Dynamic Delays

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timeout, logic

Guys I wanna make conditional or dynamic delays in AngularJS.
I know we can have fixed time delays using `timeout`, What i want is to make it dynamic like following if condition not meets than it waits more:

```
var time =500;
$timeout(function(){
                 if(success==false){
                      time =5000;
                  }
                },time);
```

SO if condition not meets then delay increases. Actually I want to wait for data to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using $timeout (or setTimeout, regardless of angular) registers the callback function for delayed execution immediately, and therefore changing the value of the "time" variable within the callback does not affect the actual delay.

If you're waiting for data to load, you have other options like using promises, in angular you can use the $q service - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
and resolve the promise once the data is available

Another option, if you're using UI-router is to use the "resolve" property of a state, to make sure data is loaded before the state is switched to.